# Brute-force mechanisme in Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, security, fosuserbundle, brute-force

I have a security issue on my symfony app with brute-force.

Since two days, I read a lot of documentations and i tried everything to understand what's happen on /login_check in Symfony.

The app use the not so good FOSUserBundle for user management.

My question is very simple : How can i add a security brute-force system in Symfony 2.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to reduce bruteforce:

- assure that the passwords of user are stong
- you can setup a recaptcha
- set up a minimal time between login attempt for the same username
- set up minimal time between same ip login attempt (independant of username used)